# Directive RemoveHandler working with PHP5.6 and PHP 7

Tags: apache2, php, fastcgi

I have 2 linode servers each hosting a website. Site A runs under Ubuntu 14.04/Apache2/Mysql/PHP 5.59, Site B runs under Ubuntu 16.04/Apache2/Mysql/PHP 7.0, and I am using Webmin/Virtualmin to manage them. Recently I tried to install PHP7.2 on site B, there were some problems during the installation but I think I eventually overcome them, only to find out when I open my site, index.php got downloaded instead of parsed by Apache. Through some digging, I found out the apache configuration of site B is like

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5.6
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.0
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.2
FCGIWrapper /home/tv/fcgi-bin/php5.6.fcgi .php5.6
FCGIWrapper /home/tv/fcgi-bin/php7.0.fcgi .php7.0
FCGIWrapper /home/tv/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php7.2
FCGIWrapper /home/tv/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php
</Directory>
<Directory /home/tv/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.peaceevertvimg.org
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://peaceevertvimg.org:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.peaceevertvimg.org
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://peaceevertvimg.org:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5.6
RemoveHandler .php7.0
RemoveHandler .php7.2
php_admin_value engine Off
```

I had to comment out

```
#RemoveHandler .php
#php_admin_value engine
```

to get site B working.
I was wondering why virtualmin would automatically add these directives which cause the website to malfunction, while I realized actually these directives also exists for site A. However, site A is running perfectly. Here is site A's corresponding directives

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/w/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/w/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/w/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.weiwei-tv.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://weiwei-tv.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.weiwei-tv.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://weiwei-tv.com:1911/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
php_admin_value engine Off
```

Both of the sites run PHP under FastCGI mode.
So why does "RemoveHandler .php" cause problem on Site B(PHP7.2) while it doesn't on Site A(PHP5.59)?